# facebook ios api issues

Tags: ios, facebook

I am using facebook api for ios but when I logged in I got this error message

```
Two-stage rotation animation is deprecated. This application should use the smoother single-stage animation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your app is using one of these methods, which were deprecated in iOS 5.0:

```
didAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
willAnimateSecondHalfOfRotationFromInterfaceOrientation:duration:
```

You need to modify your view controllers to override `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` instead, and to not override any of the "HalfOfRotation" methods.